# iOS TableViewCell lifecycle - set outlets

Tags: ios, uitableview, outlet

What TablleViewCell method is called once the outlets of a custom TableViewCell are set when the TableViewCell is instantiated from a storyboard? So a method similar to viewDidLoad essentially. I tried awakeFromNib but it appears that outlets aren't set there as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
layoutSubviews
```

does the trick.